# Show that $R[x]/xR[x]\cong R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Show that $R[x]/xR[x]\cong R$, where $R$ is a commutative ring.

My first thought was that I would need to use one of the homomorphism theorems. 
I was thinking that I would need a surjective ring homomorphism, and that it  should be $\varphi(p) = p(a)$ or $\psi(p) = p(0)$. I'm not sure.
Then $\ker \varphi = \{p\mid p(a) = 0\}$ and $\ker\psi = \{p\mid p(0) = 0\}$.
And from what I understand, $p$ is informally $p = a_0+a_1x+\dotsb+a_nx^n$, $a_i\in R$.

Then I considered $xR[x]$. I believe that this is the set $\{xp\mid p\in R[x] \}$.

But then I'm not sure where to go from there, how to fit the pieces together. I was hoping for some guidance. Thanks!

Comment: That is, the polynomial in R[x]/xR[x] is strictly determined by its constant term. But the other terms are "absorbed" into xR[x].

Comment: Sum(0 to infinity)a_ix^i  + {  Sum(1 to infinity) b_i x^i | b_i are in R)}=             a_0 +Sum(1 to infinity)a_ix^i +{Sum(1 to infinity) b_i x^i |b_i are in R} = a_0+{Sum(1 to infinity) (b_i-a_i)x^i | b_i are in R} = a_0+{Sum(1 to infinity)c_i x^i | c_i are in R}

Comment: The elements are literally r+xR[x]  for r in R. It is easy to show these cosets are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Put $f\colon R[x] \to R$, $f(p(x)) = p(0)$. Check that this is a ring morphism. Also, given $a \in R$, $f(a) = a$, so $f$ is an epimorphism. Finally, if $p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k$, we have $f(p(x)) = a_0$. You can check that $\ker f = x\,R[x]$ directly, by factoring $x$ out, if $p(x) \in \ker f$. On the other hand, if $p(x) \in x\,R[x]$, then $f(p(x)) = 0$ (why?).

Now conclude using the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Why do you bother with morphism and stuff when you can easily do it from first principles? Is it supposed to be practice for "real" problems?

Comment: This sort of reasoning appears again in a similar way when you study field extensions and quotients of $K[x]$... might as well start getting used now.

Comment: I will think about your post some more. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Feel free to ask about anything you don't understand.